# Is there a way to cd back multiple times in bash?

Tags: bash, cd-command

I often use `cd -` to go back to where I was. How can I do this multiple times in bash? Or would zsh or some other tool support this?

Comment: Check this out http://superuser.com/a/449705/235569

Comment: @Braiam: The poster is looking to go to a previously-visited directory, not a directory above their current directory.

Comment: Since I can't edit, I've used pushd but find it basically unusable since it requires you to do all of this work ahead of time (basically you have to manage it). I'm REALLY surprised what I want to do is not supported; it is 2013

Comment: Check your notifications, there is a edit on queue, you can cancel that and edit your question.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In zsh, there's an `auto_pushd` option. This option makes `cd` behave like `pushd`. Then you can just use `popd` to go back to previous directories.

```
~ $ setopt auto_pushd
~ $ cd /
/ $ cd /var
/var $ cd /usr
/usr $ dirs
/usr /var / ~
/usr $ popd
/var $ popd
/ $ popd
~ $
```

---

In Bash, you can alias `cd` to `pushd`.

```
alias cd=pushd
```

The one downside of this is that you will lose `cd`'s three flags. From the `cd` help entry:

> -L      force symbolic links to be followed
>   -P      use the physical directory structure without following symbolic links
>   -e      if the -P option is supplied, and the current working directory
>               cannot be determined successfully, exit with a non-zero status

If you ever have to use the actual `cd` builtin instead of the alias, you can use one of these:

- `'cd'` - Quoting the command makes the shell not resolve the alias and use the
  normal cd.
- `\cd` - Backslashes quote characters. If you quote one character of a word, the
  shell treats the whole word as quoted.
- `builtin cd` - This directly tells the shell to use the builtin instead of the alias.

Comment: cool, is there a way to do this in bash or just zsh?

Comment: @timpone: See the edit to my answer.

Comment: thx for pointing out tradeoffs.

Comment: Regarding the bash solution: there are more tradeoffs to be considered. E.g., I would too often write cd, meaning cd ~, and getting the swap of the two dirs at the top of the stack. I prefer simply using pushd when I need it. But I always take one alias with me: `alias ad=pushd` (ad stands for alternate directory)

Answer (score 25):

Here's a quick and dirty way to conveniently bookmark directories and jump back to them:

```
$ a() { alias $1="cd $PWD"; }
```

Go somewhere and type:

```
$ a 1
```

You now have a command called `1` which does `cd` the directory that is current at this time. Later just type:

```
$ 1
```

And presto, back to that directory. I find this very useful.

Comment: +1. This is an excellent idea. It will break if your current working directory has a space in it somewhere though. To fix that, you should put `$PWD` in double quotation marks: `"$PWD"`.

Comment: Now all you need is to make it keep a list of the bookmarks, so you can have a command to remove them (so that you don't accidentally delete non-bookmark aliases) or clear all of them.

Answer (score 20):

### bash

I found a script, available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20091025214940/http://www.geocities.com/h2428/petar/bash_acd.htm), that solved this issue for me. With this you can type `cd --` to see the last 10 directories that you've used. It'll look something like this:

```
0  ~/Documents/onedir
1  ~/Music/anotherdir
2  ~/Music/thirddir
3  ~/etc/etc
```

To go to `~/Music/thirddir` just type `cd -2`

### zsh

oh-my-zsh provides some really nice functionality for this (at least I think it's oh-my-zsh that sets this).

Basically, `d` is aliased to `dirs -v | head -10`

`dirs` is a zsh built-in command and shows the last directories you've been to.

Also, `1` is aliased to `cd -1` and so on for all numbers to `9`.

In practice, it works like this:

```
$ pwd
/home/me/Documents/gems/java_regex/lib

$ d
0       ~/Documents/gems/java_regex/lib
1       ~/Documents/gems/java_regex
2       ~/Documents/gems
3       ~/Documents
4       ~

$ 2
~/Documents/gems

$ pwd
/home/me/Documents/gems
```

Comment: acd_func can be found at: 
https://github.com/djoot/all-bash-history/blob/master/acd_func.sh

Comment: Archived link for the geocities link: https://web.archive.org/web/20091025214940/http://www.geocities.com/h2428/petar/bash_acd.htm

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `pushd` builtin in bash to push new working directories onto the directory stack. Use `popd` to pop directories of the stack in order to return to the previous working directories.

Comment: thx, should have mentioned that I tried pushd in past but was really cumbersome. Just surprised this doesn't exist.

Comment: @timpone: Maybe you could try aliasing `cd` to `pushd`. Some suggestions on this are discussed in [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/aliasing-cd-to-pushd-is-it-a-good-idea).

Comment: thx, upvoted for response

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We can make your `cd` command more powerful. Bash profile allows us to customize it the way we want.

Rather than doing multiple `cd` to navigate up the directory, we can use *alias*

For example :

```
alias ..5="cd ../../../../.."
```

This will take you 5 directory up the level.

Comment: Question is "How can I hit the back button" on where I've been (Previous locations) - not "How can I go up a directory (or 5)".

Answer (score 0):

I'm using simple function found on [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10878/quickly-cd-out-of-directories) long time ago

```
 up() { local x='';for i in $(seq ${1:-1});do x="$x../"; done;cd $x; }
```

(added in my osx .profile works like a charm)